# Unable to call readMetadata, due to error message "unable to find end tag at: START_TAG seen

Tags: metadata-api

I'm trying to collect the setting from the salesforce account. I'm using metadata api sdk to collect these metadata.
following is the snippet for readMetadata

```
ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
config.setServiceEndpoint(domain + "/services/Soap/m/"+sdk_version+"/");
config.setSessionId(accessToken);
MetadataConnection metadataConnection = new MetadataConnection(config);
ReadResult readResult =
        metadataConnection.readMetadata("SecuritySettings", new String[] {"SecuritySettings"});
```

this code works fine with sdk version 47.0, but fails with later versions throwing the following exception. I need to use the later version since some settings are only available in later versions.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: unable to find end tag at:  START_TAG seen ...</lockerServiceCSP><lockerServiceNext>... @1:6421
    at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.consumeEndTag(TypeMapper.java:474)
    at com.sforce.soap.metadata.SessionSettings.load(SessionSettings.java:1355)
    at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readSingle(TypeMapper.java:722)
    at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readObject(TypeMapper.java:593)
    at com.sforce.soap.metadata.SecuritySettings.setSessionSettings(SecuritySettings.java:269)
    at com.sforce.soap.metadata.SecuritySettings.loadFields1(SecuritySettings.java:376)
    at com.sforce.soap.metadata.SecuritySettings.loadFields(SecuritySettings.java:336)
    at com.sforce.soap.metadata.SecuritySettings.load(SecuritySettings.java:329)
    at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readSingle(TypeMapper.java:722)
    at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readArray(TypeMapper.java:617)
    at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readObject(TypeMapper.java:595)
    at com.sforce.soap.metadata.ReadResult.setRecords(ReadResult.java:46)
    at com.sforce.soap.metadata.ReadResult.loadFields1(ReadResult.java:105)
    at com.sforce.soap.metadata.ReadResult.loadFields(ReadResult.java:81)
    at com.sforce.soap.metadata.ReadResult.load(ReadResult.java:75)
    at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readSingle(TypeMapper.java:722)
    at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readObject(TypeMapper.java:593)
    at com.sforce.soap.metadata.ReadMetadataResponse_element.setResult(ReadMetadataResponse_element.java:46)
    at com.sforce.soap.metadata.ReadMetadataResponse_element.loadFields1(ReadMetadataResponse_element.java:105)
    at com.sforce.soap.metadata.ReadMetadataResponse_element.loadFields(ReadMetadataResponse_element.java:81)
    at com.sforce.soap.metadata.ReadMetadataResponse_element.load(ReadMetadataResponse_element.java:75)
    at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readSingle(TypeMapper.java:722)
    at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readObject(TypeMapper.java:593)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.bind(SoapConnection.java:194)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.receive(SoapConnection.java:161)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:108)
    at com.sforce.soap.metadata.MetadataConnection.readMetadata(MetadataConnection.java:368)
```

Can someone please guide me to the missing piece here? Appreciate your help